# Help to understand this curve rolling resistance equation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, centripetal-force

I want to calculate how much rolling resistance will differ from a straight track when a train is navigating a curve. On Wikipedia there is an equation, but I couldn't find its derivation:

$$F = 1.5\frac{k}{R}+\frac{m v^2 \cos\theta}{R}- mg\tan\theta$$

How can forces be broke down to that equation?

$\frac{mv^2}{R}$ is centripetal force multiplying by $\cos\theta$ it becomes decomposed at inclined plane. What about the other part of the equation $mg \tan\theta$?

Does anybody know how to obtain it, or how it was obtained?

Comment: Please use MathJax formatting to increase the readability of your formulae. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thank you for using MathJax; however, there are multiple ways that your formatting can be improved (fraction format, cdot's rather than periods). These things aren't really necessary, but they're helpful to let the people trying to answer your question easily read what you have written. I'll propose the edit for your question so that you can see what I mean.

Comment: What is the wikipedia page? If you are quoting something and asking for help with how to understand it, you should provide a reference or a link to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part of the formula is the "resistance due to curvature" $r_c$:

$$r_c=0.01\frac{k}{R_c}$$

Where $k$ is some dimensionless parameter dependent on the train, and $R_c$ is the radius of the curve. I cannot find the rationale, but this has some coefficient in the formulae you referenced.

The second part of the formula is, as you correctly stated, the tangential component of the centripetal force $F_c$:

$$F_c=\frac{mv^2}{R_c}\cdot \cos\theta$$

As for the third term... I could not find a reference to this term with respect to the Curve Resistance acting on a train going around a flat curve, **the formula $mg\tan\theta$ is the Centripetal Force $F_c$ exerted on a vehicle traveling around a *banked* curve**.

Given that it is already 3:15 AM here, I will simply provide you with my best guess (despite being loath to do so):

The third term (the total centripetal force on a banked curve) acts in balance with the second term to describe the total centripetal force on a flat curve.